# Asp.Net Core Map vs MapWhen

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular6

In Startup.cs, I have working code:

```
app.Map("/ca", ca =>
{
    ca.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApps/AngularApp";
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    });
});
```

I thought the following is equal, but it didn't work:

```
app.MapWhen(ctx => ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/ca"), ca =>
{
    ca.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApps/AngularApp";
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    });
});
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: docs should provide some insight https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#use-run-and-map

Answer (score 3):

For `Map` and `MapWhen`, when Map is used, the matched path segment(s) are removed from HttpRequest.Path and appended to HttpRequest.PathBase for each request. When `MapWhen` is used, it did not.

For `Spa`, it will use `requestPathBase: context.Request.PathBase.ToString());`, check [SpaPrerenderingExtensions](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/7a0413434577274666ff72ee790b53cc71b22970/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions/Prerendering/SpaPrerenderingExtensions.cs#L172).

To achieve the same result, you could try to remove and append the Path by yourself.

```
            app.MapWhen(ctx => {
            if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/ca"))
            {
                ctx.Request.Path = ctx.Request.Path.Value.Replace("/ca","");
                ctx.Request.PathBase = "/ca/";
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }, ca =>
        {
            ca.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                //rest code

            });
        });
```